# How to change field name in Invoice generated by magento {In Mail & PDF}

Tags: sku

**How to change field name in Invoice generated by magento {In Mail & PDF}**
For Example i want to change the field name (Example I want to change the SKU name to PRODUCT code) in the email Print/PDFs generated by magento.
 I got the solution for the front end  I had changed the Field name SKU to PRODUCT CODE every where in customer Account  ... His invoice and View Order But m not able to change the same in Email and Print PDF.
i am Attaching an image for proper understanding for my Question
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It relies to the layout-handle "sales_email_order_items" which is called in the transactional email templates. (originally)

For New Order Email:
if this layout-handle is'nt overwritten by any layout-update of your instance 
you can find the table header in the template

```
/email/order/items.phtml
```

line 31

For Invoice Email the layout-handle is named "sales_email_order_invoice_items" and
you find your table header in the template

```
/email/order/invoice/items.phtml
```

line: 34

change the translationkey 'Sku' to whatever you want and insert the new key into a translation-file (for example to: 'email_sku')

Answer (score 1):

If you want it easy you can just translate "Sku" in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/<whateverLanguageYouUse>/locale.csv`

The problem is, then "Sku" is translated everywhere, e.g. in the product grid.